# APNS_SANDBOX tokens deactivate instantly on Amazon SNS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We use Amazon SNS to send our push notifications to different platforms. I've hit a unique snag and am looking for help to solve it.

On our APNS_SANDBOX application, a token inserted from a phone signed with a Mobile Developer and `iOS Team Provisioning` profile will instantly deactivate when a message is sent to that end point. Without error, the AWS console says the message was delivered, if I refresh the list of end points, the end point was deactivated.

Our APNS (production) push works fine, when the app is signed for Release with a proper provisioning profile. Just the sandbox won't actually deliver push notifications to the phone.

Full disclosure, I have posted on the SNS product forums for support, but it's been days and I have not had a reply.

Comment: your team provisioning profile, does it have an explicit bundle id? was it created with a development cert?

Comment: It gets signed with a developer cert and the prov profile has an explicit bundle id. When I build from command line and inspect the .ipa the aps-environment is properly set to development.

Comment: I would recommend recreating the push certificate and update the credentials in SNS. _Make sure_ that you have created a Development SSL push certificate for that bundle id as I think using the wrong env will cause this issue.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I'm facing the same issue now, did anyone resolve this?